# parametrizing set $S(0,R) \times [-a,a]$

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a cylinder: $\mathcal{D}=B(0,R)\times[-a,a]$ where $a > R > 0$ and let $\mathcal{D}$ be oriented by outer normal $n$.
Parametrize $S(0,R) \times [-a,a]$.

I am not sure how to go about this. Why is $\mathcal{D}$ a cylinder? I do not see the general picture. Would $S(0,R) \times [-a,a]$ be a cylinder without the boundary? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Assuming $ B(0,R) $ is the disc centered at 0 with radius $ R $ (a "ball" in 2D). We now take the interval $ [-a,a] $ and at each point place a copy of this disc. Think of it like stacking CDs or DVDs. Does this help illustrate why $ \mathcal D $ is a cylinder? I don't know what $ S(0,R) $ is supposed to mean here though.

Comment: Oh, now I see why it is a cylinder. $S(0,R)$ is supposed to be a sphere.